# PHp Unit testing error 'Undefined index: SERVER_NAME in /config/autoload/global.php' in ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2, phpunit

**I've just started with Zend framework 2. I want to set up unit testing for my Cart module.**

**I have followed the steps of http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/tutorials/unittesting.html**

**When I run** 
**:/var/www/AHA/CDP/module/Cart/tests$ phpunit** 
**from terminal I am getting following output:**

PHPUnit 3.7.28 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /var/www/ZF2Sample/module/Cart/tests/phpunit.xml

E

Time: 146 ms, Memory: 5.50Mb

There was 1 error:

1) Cart\tests\Cart\Controller\CartControllerTest::testIndexActionCanBeAccessed
include(/var/www/ZF2Sample/module/Admin/config/../view/error/index.phtml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

/var/www/ZF2Sample/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php:506
/var/www/ZF2Sample/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php:506
/var/www/ZF2Sample/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/View.php:205
/var/www/ZF2Sample/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/View.php:233
/var/www/ZF2Sample/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/View.php:198
/var/www/ZF2Sample/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/View/Http/DefaultRenderingStrategy.php:102
/var/www/ZF2Sample/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:468
/var/www/ZF2Sample/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:207
/var/www/ZF2Sample/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/View/Http/DefaultRenderingStrategy.php:112
/var/www/ZF2Sample/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:468
/var/www/ZF2Sample/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:207
/var/www/ZF2Sample/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Application.php:352
/var/www/ZF2Sample/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Application.php:327
/var/www/ZF2Sample/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Test/PHPUnit/Controller/AbstractControllerTestCase.php:288
/var/www/ZF2Sample/module/Cart/tests/Cart/Controller/CartControllerTest.php:30

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.

**Below is my global.php :**

```
<?php
    define('SITE_URL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/');
    define('JS_URL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/js/');
    define('CSS_URL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/css/');
    define('IMG_URL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/img/');
    return array(
        'cart_webservice_url' => "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/ecommercewebservices",
    );
?>
```

**I placed $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] = 'myproject.com'; at beginning of global.php**

**Then I got below output :**

PHPUnit 3.7.28 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /var/www/AHA/CDP/module/Cart/tests/phpunit.xml

**I searched a lot but could not find any answer . Please suggest.**

Answer (score 8):

You can setup different $_SERVER params with the following example in your phpunit.xml file.

```
<phpunit>
....
    <php>
        <server name='HTTP_HOST' value='http://localhost' />
        <server name="SERVER_NAME" value="http://foo.bar"/>
        <server name="SERVER_PORT" value="80"/>
        <server name="REMOTE_ADDR" value="127.1.2.3"/>
    </php>
....
</phpunit>
```